# Partial with respect to a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I suspect this is either an elementary issue I have forgotten how to address since my long ago undergraduate vector calculus, or a nonsensical question.  I apologize in advance either way.

There is a well explored model where the literature is full of partials with respect to a variable
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \vec{f}(\vec{x})$$
but in my reformulation of this model $\vec{x}$ is a function of other variables $\vec{y}$ so I have
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \vec{g}\big(\vec{x}(\vec{y}),\vec{y}\big).$$
How do you take a partial with respect to a function?

EDIT:

Since each $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial y_j}$ is well defined, is this as simple as abusing the chain rule,
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
=\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}
=\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\frac{1}{\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}}$$
?

Comment: May I know where did you find that expression?

Answer (score 1):

You don't. In the usual notation, $\frac\partial{\partial x_i}g$ just means taking the derivative of $g$ with respect its $i$-th entry. With this in mind, $\frac\partial{\partial x_i}g(\vec x(\vec y),\vec y)$ means evaluating the function $\frac\partial{\partial x_i}g$ at the point $(\vec x(\vec y),\vec y)$.

Edited:

Say $g$ is a function $g:\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R$. Then $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}$ (if it exists) stands for the function $\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R$ defined by
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}(a,b)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(a+he_1,b)-g(a,b)}{h}.$$
for every $a\in\mathbb R^n$, $b\in\mathbb R^m$.
Then you can plug in the point $(a,b)=(\vec x(\vec y),\vec y)$.

Comment: If I know the function g(), then what is the function $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}$ since $\vec{x}$ is a function and not an independent variable?  $x_1$ indicates the first element of the vector $\vec{x}$

Comment: @JeffSnider Added to the answer. Is it clearer now?